# Get the most recent event in the 24 hour cycle

Tags: sql, time, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a table [**get_today_events**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fe84b/2) that shows what events are taking place today. I need to create a view that shows which events are *actual*  (that means that current time is between *actual* event and the next event according to their time in `eventtime` column) for each `scheduleid` and not take into consideration events where `is_work` column is `N`. The issue I got stuck in is that condition in this subquery :

```
select scheduleid
     , max(eventtime) as eventtime
from get_today_events
where cast(current_timestamp as time) >= eventtime
  and is_work = 'Y'
group by scheduleid
```

works fine until `current_timestamp` is between `00:00:00` and the first event after `00:00:00` – then it shows nothing. I've found a [**correct solution**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fe84b/116) but I am looking forward to find a shorter way to achieve the same thing.

**1st *edit* :**

To make it clear I am posting an example with expected data for ***STD*** `scheduleid`. There are five time intervals (**TI** hereinafter) :

```
--------------------------------------------
scheduleid | eventname | eventtime | is_work
--------------------------------------------
   STD        Suspend    02:00:00       Y
   STD        Start      04:00:00       Y
   STD        Stop       05:00:00       Y
   STD        Suspend    19:00:00       Y
   STD        Start      02:00:00       Y
   STD        Stop       21:00:00       N
```

- TI between **02:00:00** and 04:00:00 (actual `eventname` is `Suspend`);
- TI between 04:00:00 and 05:00:00 (actual `eventname` is `Start`);
- TI between 05:00:00 and 19:00:00 (actual `eventname` is `Stop`);
- TI between 19:00:00 and <del>21:00:00</del> **02:00:00** (actual `eventname` is `Start`);
- <del>TI between 21:00:00 and 02:00:00 (actual `eventname` is `Stop`).</del>

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with _"Is not valid after 00:00:00 and between the first event after 00:00:00"_

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: With this query some events are not shown at all in this interval of time, because there is no `CAST(current_timestamp as TIME) >= MAX(EVENTTIME)` - they all are greater then `CAST(current_timestamp as TIME)`.

Comment: Please post some sample data, and the result you want to have.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel : There are two links in the post with table structure and result I want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to get the most recent event in the 24 hour cycle.

```
MAX(CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIME >= EVENTTIME THEN EVENTTIME END)
```

gives the latest time before `CURRENT_TIME` and `NULL` if there is none.

You can then use `COALESCE` to replace that `NULL` with the last event before midnight.

```
SELECT
    SCHEDULEID,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIME >= EVENTTIME THEN EVENTTIME END),
             MAX(EVENTTIME)) as EVENTTIME
FROM GET_TODAY_EVENTS
WHERE IS_WORK = 'Y'
GROUP BY SCHEDULEID
```

If you want to get the details of these events you can `JOIN` with the original table.

```
SELECT mr.SCHEDULEID,mr.EVENTTIME,gte.EVENTTYPEID
  FROM
  (SELECT
      SCHEDULEID,
      COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIME >= EVENTTIME THEN EVENTTIME END),
               MAX(EVENTTIME)) as EVENTTIME
     FROM GET_TODAY_EVENTS
    WHERE IS_WORK = 'Y'
    GROUP BY SCHEDULEID) AS mr
 JOIN GET_TODAY_EVENTS gte 
   ON (gte.SCHEDULEID=mr.SCHEDULEID AND gte.EVENTTIME=mr.EVENTTIME)
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fe84b/52)

Comment: There is always actual event (if there is only one event then it is always shown as actual, if there are two then in the time interval between the first and the second the actual event is the first and in the interval between the second and the first the actual event is the second).

Comment: I'm not understanding still. "and in the interval between the second and the first the actual event is the second" - should that be "and in the interval between the second and the **third** the actual event is the second"

Comment: Answer has been edited. Now it gets the most recent event - even if that event happened yesterday.